# Getting error while joining fabric composer channel

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Background of the work:

I am trying to extend the Composer environment have multiple Organisation in it. 
I could do that by modifying configtx.yaml, crypto-config.yaml & docker-compose.yml files.

Issue facing:

When I created a channel using `startFabric.sh` and try to join new Org's peers in it

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block
```

I am getting below error.

> 2017-07-14 10:03:09.046 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
>   2017-07-14 10:03:09.046 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
>   2017-07-14 10:03:09.049 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>   Error: genesis block file not found open composerchannel.block: no such file or directory`

My environment details.

> composer-cli                   v0.9.2
>   composer-admin                 v0.9.2
>   composer-client                v0.9.2
>   composer-common                v0.9.2
>   composer-runtime-hlf           v0.9.2
>   composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.9.2
>
> npm 3.10.10
>   node v6.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to extend the composer development fabric, I think you would be better off creating a network from scratch following the hyperledger fabric documentation found at
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
The development fabric defined by composer isn't meant to be a template for how to define a fabric, but rather as the simplest setup possible to provide a real hyperledger fabric to develop and test against.
The examples provided by hyperledger fabric are best suited for understanding and creating your own custom fabric and hyperledger composer should be able to work with that custom topology through appropriate configuration of the connection profile and importing of appropriate crypto material using the composer identity import command.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `composerchannel.block` in the working directory (`working_dir` defined in your docker-compose.yaml) of your `peer0.org2.example.com` container.

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.